# Java TreeMap time complexity - lowerKey

Tags: java, time-complexity, treemap

What is the time complexity of the `lowerKey()` operation in Java implementation of `TreeMap` ?

I think it is log(n) but I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.

The complexity of more basic operation is well documented:

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the
>   containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

BTW: I'm also interested in the complexity of `subMap()`. I guess that a log(n) complexity of `lowerKey()` will allow log(n) time for **constant size** `subMap()`.

Comment: `lowerKey` is definitely O(log n).  `subMap` is O(1) and returns an implementation with O(log n) extra overhead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`lowerKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lowerKey%28K%29) is a search in a balanced binary search tree, so it's obviously `O(log n)`. You might want to read the source code, e.g. from [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/TreeMap.java.html), to see how the tree is traversed.

Similarly, each operation with a `NavigableMap` returned from `subMap()` also requires `O(log n)` because you will need to traverse the tree to find elements you want.