# How to access the linked list inside the LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

LinkedHashMap is supposed to contain an insertion-order linked list. Is there any way to access that list? I can't find anything in the javadocs for it.

Comment: Does `keySet()` do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @shmosel I have a key-value type structure that requires next(), previous() in something hopefully better than O(n). But I'm hoping to keep the efficiency of the hashmap for the other operations.

Answer (score 2):

No, those are implementation details and should never be exposed to the external world.

Comment: So theirs no way to get the Previous() and Next() of a key in something better than O(n) using the iterator?

Comment: @WinterDev I did not say this. Your question was about accessing guts of some another structure. Also, are you sure that previous and next are not O(1) actually? You sure you need a LinkedHashMap?

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't, but depending on what you're trying to do, the iterator returned by `iterator()` may be sufficient.

Comment: That sucks, I was hoping to get access to .previous() and .next() in O(1) instead of looping through the entries in O(n) to get the previous and next.

Comment: @WinterDev next() is O(1)

Comment: @PeterLawrey If I have a key K and want to get the equivalent of K.next(), I have to loop through the iterator until I find K and then get the next one, which is O(n)

Comment: @WinterDev in that case,t his is not an intended use case for this Map. I suggest using a NavigableMap which has next and previous.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The methods kinda resemble TreeMap for getting the ceiling and the floor of a key but my problem with TreeMap was the time complexity of the other operations were all slower than a hashmap. I can't find the time complexity for NavigableMap, do you have any insight on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767130/java-treemap-time-complexity-lowerkey

Comment: @WinterDev it's O(log n) like basically all other operations.